# openssl and PKG_CONFIG_PATH problems while configuring mongolite package from R

Tags: openssl, mongodb, r, configure, pkg-config

The package "mongolite" won't install itself when trying in RStudio. So I downloaded it from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/, extracted it in the folder which manages the R packages `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` then launched `sudo ./configure` but I got this error

```
Found pkg-config cflags and libs!
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lresolv
./configure: line 71: /bin/R: No such file or directory
./configure: line 72: /bin/R: No such file or directory
./configure: line 73: /bin/R: No such file or directory
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl/sasl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev, libsasl2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel, cyrus-sasl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev, sasl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`libssl-dev` and `libsasl2-dev` are installed and `pkg-config` is in my PATH so I can't find any way to solve the problem. I also tried to launch 
`./configure PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/"` because this is where the file `openssl.pc` is located but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally re-ran `install.packages("mongolite")` in RStudio and it miraculously worked fine.